# Carrying Pistol License on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, muktzeh, eruv-chatzerot

Situation: you are licensed to carry a concealed pistol.  You live inside an eruv.  You choose to carry your pistol on shabbat.

**What is the status of the Concealed Pistol License (CPL) ID card?**  Can we say that the CPL ID is "supporting" the pistol, and therefore it is not *muksah* and can be carried also?  Or do we say that the CPL ID is not needed, because we can prove to the police that we are licensed after the fact?

Aside: I'm thinking of getting a scan of my CPL printed on to a t-shirt...

Comment: Carrying the pistol itself is not *muktzeh*?

Comment: No, according to many opinions, including my LOR, carrying a pistol for self defense in an eruv on shabbat is permitted.

Comment: P.S. here is a nice discussion https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-on-ou/carrying-gun-shabbos-issues-possible-conclusions/

Comment: "Or do we say that the CPL ID is not needed, because we can prove to the police that we are licensed after the fact" So is it neccessary to carry the ID? Why would anyoe ever bother carrying it, if it isn't neccessary to carry?

Comment: @Salmononius2 If you are detected by the police to be carrying a pistol, they will want to know that you are licensed.  If you don't have the card, they may arrest you.  The process of proving that you are registered will take a bit of time and inconvenience.  By carrying the card with you, you save time and aggravation.  So the question is about  balancing the potential inconvenience of being detained by the police on shabbat vs. carrying the CPL ID with you.

Comment: Maybe you can tape a reduced-size copy of the license card to a place it safely fits on the gun?

Comment: @gary indeed, perhaps around the magazine.  I'm still curious about my original question.

Comment: That's great, I was thinking around the clip area also --- btw, the t-shirt might be a nice deterrent by itself, but in some neighborhoods, you'd better have the hardware on hand to avoid potentially embarrassing(or worse) mishaps.

Comment: what about wearing it as a necklace? you'd probably have to do it in a way that the card is completing the loop. CYLOR

Comment: I don’t understand why the license would be muktzeh. It has a purpose on Shabbos - proving to the police that you own the pistol. So you can do it another way, so what? I’ve never heard anyone say you have to find a doorstop if you can designate a heavy rock before Shabbos.

Comment: @Menachem My LOR told me that things like keys etc. should only be worn if they are actually made into jewelry (gold plated tie pin etc.). Wearing a normally not worn item just so you can carry it does not count.

Comment: @DonielF I don't either but a friend of mine told me he thought it would be.  THe argument is like this; the gun is allowed for _pekua nefesh_ (preservation of life); the ID card is not required to protect life; since you can technically carry the gun without it (and have to prove after the fact) that makes it not necessary.

Comment: @Gary repeat after me "a magazine feeds ammunition, a clip secures your tie" :-)

Comment: Why only ask about carrying within an erev.  Would not any answer apply also to carrying without an erev?  We are talking about a d'rabbonan prohibition (carrying) and a d'orita permission.

Comment: Because, if there is no Eruv, I think the bar is much higher to justify the gun.  Basically, imminent danger.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I got a response from a rabbi affiliated with the OU, he runs an "ask the rabbi" type service.  The CPL ID card is not muksah if it is legally required to carry the gun.

Comment: That's the response that Israeli's get when asking a LOR; the gun license and an extra magazine are permitted, nay, required in order to carry the gun on Shabbat.